# Error in `/usr/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f7c3c017260

Tags: python, numpy, flask, race-condition, apscheduler

I'm developing a website in Python using the (excellent) Flask framework. In the backend code I use APScheduler to run some cron-like jobs every minute, and I use Numpy to calculate some Standard Deviations. Don't know whether the usage of these modules matter, but I thought I'dd better mention them since I guess they might be the most likely to be the cause.

Anyway, in the middle of operation, Python itself seemed to crash, giving the following:

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f7c3c017260 ***
```

I might be wrong, but as far as I know, this is pretty serious. So my question is actually; what could cause this, and how can I get more information about a crash like this? What does the `(out)` mean? I can't really reproduce this, but it happened 4 times in about 5 months now. I'm running the standard Python 2.7 on Ubuntu server 14.04

I searched around and found a couple discussions about similar crashes, of which one thing comes back: concurrency seems to be related somehow (which is why I included the usage of APScheduler).

If anybody has any idea how I could debug this or what could possibly be the cause of this; all tips are welcome!

Comment: Congrats, you've found a bug in Python or some package you use with native code. Not much you can do.

Comment: You may try to run the application using valgrind or some other tool like that. This would give a lot more information about memory allocation/free. However it's going to be quite slower than running python normally.

Comment: You can install the [debug symbol packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash) of python from the ubuntu repositories and run your program with that. With the information of the full stack trace report the bug to the ubuntu team.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

I had an unused dependency: spacy == 1.6.0
removing it solved the issue.
(maybe upgrading spacy version could also work)

[spacy](https://spacy.io/) is written in [Cython](http://cython.org/) - an optimising static compiler for Python. So it might be related to sum bug memory allocation in spacy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue too.

It turns out that I passed a 1D array to a `numba`-compiled function which takes a 2D array. :P